# Windows 7 Log off actions

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, logoff

I have and application that need's to recognize when user logs off the system(Windows 7 OS). So, when user logs off from system, I need to log out user from application. I tried with batch file(put it in "GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff") and to run a browser with log off url. Batch file starts(i inserted command for windows alert and alert shows up during log off) but it seems that browser does not start. When i run this batch file without logging of the sistem, all actions I want are made. So does anyone have any solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: web application (asp.net MVC). So the idea is to run log off action ("rootUrl/LogOff") to log off the user from the application before log off from the system is completed. Obviously, the solution with batch file is not good. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, once the log off operation has started Windows won't execute any new programs. So apparently you'll have to run a watchdog program that will handle [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx) system message and make the http connection. Such a program can be coded using many languages or even with an AutoHotkey script.

Comment: You could try to use Windows task scheduler, trigger "disconnect user query"; I think this is linked to the handle @wOxxOm mentioned...